# Function name as argument but with different number of argument

Tags: c++, arguments

I have written a bisection solver with a function name as argument and that function has only one argument:

```
double Bisection(double(*func)(double), double xLower, double xUpper, double xEPS = 1e-9, double yEPS = 1e-9);
```

Now I want to apply this solver in a Beta inverse cumulative probability function where the CDF is already known. But this CDF has three argument where the last two arguments are known:

```
double CDF(double x, double alpha, double beta)
```

How should I use this CDF as an argument of the solver by reducing the number of arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to replace your C-style function pointer with a C++ std::function:

```
double Bisection(std::function<double(double)> func, double xLower, double xUpper, double xEPS = 1e-9, double yEPS = 1e-9);
```

The implementation will be the same as before.  Now you can use `std::bind()` to call it:

```
double alpha, beta, xLower, xUpper; // TODO: assign
Bisection(std::bind(CDF, _1, alpha, beta), xLower, xUpper);
```

What `std::bind()` does there is to convert your three-argument CDF function into a one-argument (`_1`) function by binding the second and third arguments to variables.

You can't use `std::bind()` with your original C-style function pointer, as discussed here: [convert std::bind to function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238050/convert-stdbind-to-function-pointer)

Comment: This is really a great solution!