# How do you enumerate the formats, resolutions and framerates in libav for v4l2?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, libav

So start with, let's set some context regarding libav (ffmpeg):

Yes, I'm aware that this is a 'per backend' thing, and for some (eg. avfoundation) although it includes the code to enumerate these options, can only output them as [error](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavdevice/avfoundation.m#L409) [messages](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavdevice/avfoundation.m#L507) when you pass an invalid combination of input parameters and attempt to open a device.

Other implementations, eg. the v4l2 driver implements [list_formats](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavdevice/v4l2.c#L1110) that can be seen using:

`ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i "/dev/video0"`

However, the [implementation of this function](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavdevice/v4l2.c#L289) also just logs out the formats.

Now, I'm well aware that you can trigger the these functions (depending on the backend) by forming some combination of options in an `AVDictionary` and passing the result to `av_find_input_format`.

So, not possible right?

However, as per [c++ how to use lambdas to set ffmpeg's av_log_set_callback() to a member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48757736/c-how-to-use-lambdas-to-set-ffmpegs-av-log-set-callback-to-a-member-functio) you can rebind the logging function in libav to capture this output.

Right... so now this is where I'm stuck. In theory I can use `vsprintf` to convert the log callback (ie. `char *fmt, va_list args` into a string, and collect the result.

However, I can't figure out how to actually *implement* something that does the following:

- build a valid AVDictionary with the required properties
- set the log callback
- av_find_input_format / avf_read_header / whatever
- get the output of the log <--- how do I do this?
- clear the log callback

How can I capture the log output?

Please, no vague hand waving, post actual code. There's a [basic example](https://github.com/leixiaohua1020/simplest_ffmpeg_device) of how to do this which already does all the steps except the log capture.

Note that the answer to the SO post linked about about using lambdas is answered with "You can't use a capturing lambda, use a global in the log callback function", however, I'm posting this question because that answer *lacks detail* about specifically how to do that in a **thread safe** way, given that the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.4/group__lavu__log.html#ga14034761faf581a8b9ed6ef19b313708) specifically states:

> The callback must be thread safe, even if the application does not use threads itself as some codecs are multithreaded.