# How to typedef std::function with unsigned char array as pararmeter

Tags: c++, bind

I am trying to push many function pointer into a vector for later use. However, I run into problems of type problem

```
/// in the h file
typedef std::function<int(unsigned char *)> func_t;

class A
{
  void init();
  // after some codes declaration
  private:
  B b;
  std::vector<func_t> func_list;

}

class B
{
   int somefunction(unsigned char *);
}

// elsewise in the cpp file of class A
A::init()
{
  func_t f = std:bind(&B::somefunction, &b, std::placeholders::_1);
  func_list.push_back(f);
}
```

The error seem to occur at the point of std::bind, the error read as

```
 initializing: cannot convert from 'std::Binder<std::Unforced, void(__thiscall B::*)(unsigned char *), B*, const std::_Ph<1> &>' to std::function<int(unsigned char*)>
```

The problem goes away if I change the variable f from `func_t` to `auto` . Though subsequently I would have the same problem to push into the vector func_list. So I guess my problem is with the type definition or std::bind definition

Thanks

Comment: Seem to work for me: https://godbolt.org/z/j4j7d9vhe What's your compiler and C++ versions?

Comment: @Ranoiaetep i think it'll compile but you should get a runtime error

Comment: @Ranoiaetep nvm, you're right.. not sure why i was getting the same error OP did at first..

Comment: The error shows the member function returning void. It does not match the code.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Hi using visual studio 2022(v143) and C++ language version ISO C++ 14 standard

Answer (score 1):

std::bind returns "A function object of unspecified type T, for which std::is_bind_expression::value == true" [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

I don't think there is a way to get bind to return func_t (according to [convert std::bind to function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238050/convert-stdbind-to-function-pointer)), but I may be wrong.

Edit: as @Ranoiaetep pointed out, leaving it as func_t without changing to auto, works too.

Changing to auto does work though:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
typedef std::function<int(unsigned char *)> func_t;

class B
{
public:
int somefunction(unsigned char *);
};

int B::somefunction(unsigned char *) {
    return 1;
};

class A
{
    public:
  void init();
  private:
  B b;
  std::vector<func_t> func_list;

};

void A::init()
{
  auto f = std::bind(&B::somefunction, &b, std::placeholders::_1);
  func_list.push_back(f);
};

int main()
{
    A* a = new A();
    a->init();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't convert a bind expression to function pointer. However, an `std::function` can store any *CopyConstructible [Callable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable)*, which includes bind expressions.